# How to enable a submit button after multiple form fields have been verified

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have a form with 5 input tag and a disabled Submit button that I would like to enable once the 4 out of 5 mandatory field fill and validated, how can I do this?

(-First I have to validate field and then after only submit button will enable-)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: you should come up with your code. like what validation you have done...

Comment: show us some effort, we help you with YOUR code, we do not write it for you!

Comment: Please post your code on jsfiddle.net so we can try to help you.

Comment: see i have do this but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/DRcSj/
please can you help me through this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check after each of field validation, how may valid fields you got. when you got 4, enable the button.

You need to do counter that +1 when field is valid. If it was valid and now invalid you need to -1.

Comment: see i have do this but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/DRcSj/
please can you help me through this.why its not working

Comment: Put your script with the function on the button of the body

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DRcSj/1/ look on the left bar on fiddle

Comment: i want that if suppose occupation field remain blank then also submit button become enable.then what i have to do???

Comment: Here your mistake: http://jsfiddle.net/DRcSj/2/

Comment: You need to continue if the element i == 2 (the 3rd)

Comment: ok.got it means if suppose there 5 to 6 field that are not mandatory then just add those element as above statement and put continue..right??there is no other method for doing this..

Comment: I would do it with jquery and in different way but yes.

Comment: You should post it on different question :) I can't answer that here. Mark this as solved and open another one with you jsfiddle.

Comment: now suppose I have include validation for email.Now if I have entered not validate email id then will submit became enable or not??I have done validation before this event..
If yes then how to prevent enabling until all field are correctly entered.

Comment: Read what I said: "You should post it on different question :) I can't answer that here. Mark this as solved and open another one with you jsfiddle."

Answer (score 0):

For all 5 input tags add a onchange() event, all of them calling the same function.
In that function, check if 4 inputs are correct, and if so enable the submit button.

Also, some of your code could help us give you a better answer, but none will do all the work for you(not for free at least).

Comment: see i have do this but its not working http://jsfiddle.net/DRcSj/
please can you help me through this.